# Slice bounds out of range

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

The following code throws `slice bounds out of range` error.

```
func main()  {
    file, err := os.Open("mails.mbox")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    m := mbox.NewReader(file) // bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for {
        data, err := m.NextMessage() // .Scan()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unexpected error after NextMessage(): %v", err)
        }
        go saveMessage(data)
    }

    // By now we should not have any messages inside.
    if _, err := m.NextMessage(); err != io.EOF {
        log.Fatalf("We still have data: %v", err)
    }
}

func saveMessage(data io.Reader) {
    msg, err := mail.ReadMessage(data)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // insert msg into database
}
```

I wanna process the `saveMessage` function concurrently.

100 at a time or based on the free memory.

Comment: Be more specific please. What's the error? Can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mbox reader and the message readers returned from NextMessage are not safe for concurrent access. The program panics because of a data race within the mbox implementation.

Fix by slurping up the message data before starting the goroutine:

```
for {
    data, err := m.NextMessage() // .Scan()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unexpected error after NextMessage(): %v", err)
    }
    msg, err := mail.ReadMessage(data)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go saveMessage(msg)
}

...

func saveMessage(msg *mail.Message) {
    // insert msg into database
}
```